# Problems using javascript regex to validate date

Tags: javascript, regex, date, validation

I'm trying to use javascript regex to validate a date input, but it is returning valid dates as invalid. I'm not an expert on regex so I don't know what is wrong with it:

```
/^([0-9]d{2})+(\.|-|\/)+([0-9]d{2})+(\.|-|\/)+([0-9]d{4})+$/
```

I want these date formats to be accepted:

23/04/2001

23-04-2001

23.04.2001

Originally I had this, but it was accepting dates with other characters on the end like 23/04/2001jhsdgf:

```
/\d{2}(\.|-|\/)\d{2}(\.|-|\/)\d{4}/;
```

Comment: A simple regex check isn't enough. `00-00-0000` matches your regex.

Comment: That is very true, how do you suggest I make sure its an actual date? 99/99/9999 would also match.

Comment: I've added my answer. The date looks like UK date, you might want to omit `/` from the separator list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your original regex and just add the `^` and `$` from your new one to it. Problem solved.

EDIT: Although, really, the `(\.|-|\/)` is a mess and should be `[.\/-]` instead.

EDIT 2: That said, if you make the first one `([.\/-])` then you can replace the second one with `\1` and then it would require both separators to be the same.

Comment: Okay, won't my original regex allow letters as well? How do I specify numeric only and have it work properly?

Comment: `\d` means "any digit". It only allows numbers.

Answer (score 4):

You can check if a date is syntactically correct using a regex such as this one:

```
/^(\d{1,2})([-\.\/])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{4})$/
```

- `^` and `$` match beginning and end of string respectively
- `\d{1,2}` matches 1 or 2 digits
- `\d{4}` matches exactly 4 digits
- `\2` matches the string captured in second capturing group (`- . /`)

If matched, you can use the matched date, month and year to build a new date and compare the resulting date, month, year with the matched values. Here is a function which does just that:

```
function checkDate(dateText) {
    var match = dateText.match(/^(\d{1,2})([-\.\/])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{4})$/);
    // "31.04.2012" -> ["31.04.2012", "31", ".", "04", "2012"]
    if (match === null) {
        return false;
    }
    var date = new Date(+match[4], +match[3] - 1, +match[1]);
    return date.getFullYear() == +match[4] && 
      date.getMonth() == +match[3] - 1 && 
      date.getDate() == +match[1];
}
checkDate("30.04.2013"); // true
checkDate("31-04-2013"); // false (April has 30 days)
```

- `+` is used to convert string to number (`+"01"` becomes `1`)
- Months are 0 based (0 = January, 1 = February, ...)
- The above example assumes that the date is in `dd-mm-yyyy` format

The [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object attempts to correct invalid dates. Attempting to create a date such as `31-4-2013` yields `1-05-2013`, the above function compares the resulting date with input parameters to check the validity.

Comment: Thanks, that has helped my understand things a whole lot better! For user friendliness and less need to validate, I have decided to use a JQuery UI datepicker and disable keypresses on that input. Seems to work a treat. Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome. You can make the input `readonly`.

Comment: For validate: mm/dd/yyyy
<pre><code>
function checkDate(dateText) {
var match = dateText.match(/^(\d{1,2})([\/])(\d{1,2})\2(\d{4})$/);
        if (match === null) {
            return false;
        }

        var date = new Date(+match[4], +match[1] - 1, +match[3]);
        return date.getFullYear() === +match[4] && date.getMonth() === +match[1] - 1 && date.getDate() === +match[3];
}
</code>
</pre>