# Incorporate leading zero in my date validation

Tags: javascript, validation, date

Here is my current date validation function:

```
  isValidDate = function(day,month,year) {
    var dteDate;
    dteDate=new Date(year,month,day);
    return ((day.toString()===dteDate.getDate().toString()) && (month.toString()===dteDate.getMonth().toString()) && (year.toString()===dteDate.getFullYear().toString()));
  }
```

Then later I check the fields:

```
checkFields = function() {
  var iDate = $("inspect_date").value;
  if(iDate.length > 0) {
    var a = iDate.split("/"); 
    if(isValidDate(a[0],a[1]-1,a[2]) == false){
      alert("You have entered an invalid date. Please amend!");
      return false;
    }
```

So at the moment it doesn't accept dates in the format dd/mm/yyy which is what I want - the function doesn't like the leading zero.

I tried to fix it in this way:

```
isValidDate = function(day,month,year) {
  var dteDate;
  dteDate=new Date(year,month,day);

  var day = dteDate.getDate();
  var month = dteDate.getMonth() + 1;
  var year = dteDate.getFullYear();

  var formatted =
      (day < 10 ? "0" : "") + day + "/"  +
      (month < 10 ? "0" : "") + month + "/"  +
      year;

  return ((day.toString()===dteDate.getDate().toString()) && (month.toString()===dteDate.getMonth().toString()) && (year.toString()===dteDate.getFullYear().toString()));
}
```

But now my 'return' part is containing the wrong values when it does the comparisons.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the example date `"02/04/2012"` the first variation of your function passes `"02", 3, "2012"` as the arguments. Your function then tries to compare `"02"` with `"2"` which is obviously "not equal".

You should compare numbers as numbers. Unary `+` operator is a shortcut to convert a string to a number (`+"01"` yields `1`; you can use `parseInt` as well):

```
return
    +day === dteDate.getDate() && 
    +month === dteDate.getMonth() &&
    +year === dteDate.getFullYear();
```

[Here is another way to validate dates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14693731/87015) using RegRx and JavaScript Date object.

Comment: Could you explain what +day, +month, etc. actually are? Also when I try this code, I get my 'Invalid Date' warning still.

Comment: In my own code, do you know why I'd use `var month = dteDate.getMonth() + 1`? I got the validation code from somewhere else and I don't understand the `+1` part.

Comment: getMonth() returns 0-based month numbers (jan=0, dec=11) where as we naturally assume that jan = 1 and dec = 12. The + 1 for convert months to natural month.